# Flutter web view change in URL not detecting

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I want to change the URL when a new page opens up with flutter web view (new version).

```dart
controller = WebViewController();

controller
..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
..loadRequest(Uri.parse(URL))
..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
onPageStarted: (String url) {
  print(url);
  setState(() {
  URL = url;
 });
}));
```

I tried:

```dart
onPageFinished: (String url) {
print('New Page Finished: $url');
setState(() {
  URL = url;
  });
},
```

and

```dart
onUrlChange: (String url){
  print(url);
  setState(() {
    URL = url;
  });
}
```

None of them seems to work.